# Deleting many to many objects in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have two models like this:

```
class Toppings(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    toppings =  models.ManyToManyField(Toppings)
```

I create a pizza and add toppings like this

```
crazy_pizza = Pizza(name = "crazy pizza")
crazy_pizza.save() 
toppings = ["pepperoni","chicken","bacon"]
for i in toppings:
    topping = Toppings(name = i)
    toppings.save()
    crazy_pizza.add(topping)
crazy_pizza.save()
```

now i want to delete all the toppings associated with crazy pizza. I run

```
crazy_pizza.toppings.clear()
```

this removes the many to many reference, how can i also delete all the actual toppings objects themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
crazy_pizza.toppings.all().delete()
```